# How to change the revision uid on node save

Tags: entities, hooks, nodes

I need to change the revison uid of 7000 nodes on a site. So I am using [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to perform this action, by publishing or saving the the 7000 nodes concerned. Then I use the [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) to update all contents. But unfortunately, the field revision_uid isn't properly updated. By cons the field log is properly updated..

```
$field_uid = field_get_items('node', $node, 'uid');
    if($field_uid){
         $node->log = $node->uid;        
         $node->revision_uid = $node->uid;
    }
```

The revision id is still the one I'm using to make this operation (1 to admin..). How can get around this problem??

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to impersonate a user while performing your operation:

```
<?php
//Save current user data/session
global $user;
$original_user = $user;
$old_state = drupal_save_session(FALSE);

$field_uid = field_get_items('node', $node, 'uid');
    if($field_uid){
         // Load new $user data
         $user = user_load($node->uid);

         $node->log = $node->uid;        
         $node->revision_uid = $user->uid;
    }

// Fail safe - if your code fails session won't be saved
$user = $original_user;
//Rever to old user and save session
drupal_save_session($old_state);
?>
```

References:

- http://drupal.org/node/1082292
- http://firedev.ro/blog/node-revision-when-doing-nodesave-gets-currently-logged-users-uid

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems correct. But actually I haven't tested it, because I solved my problem my using direct db_update..

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve my problem by using a direct db_update, here is my simple code:

```
function hook_node_update($node) {

  $node->log = $node->uid;
  $node->revision_uid = $node->uid;

  $revision_uid_updated = db_update('node_revision')
  ->fields(array(
    'uid' => $node->uid,
  ))
  ->condition('nid', $node->nid, '=')
  ->execute();

}
```

With this, I was able to reassign the revision ownership to the author of each content